# IOS replace CATiledLayer with OpenGL

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, catiledlayer

I have a remote controller app, which is using ***CATiledLayer*** to display remote desktop. All drawing is made by ***drawRect:*** method. I have some really rare crashes when resizing remote screen's resolution.

I was trying to debug this issue but nothing helped, so (after receiving some advices from my smarter colleges) I decided to rewrite my code using ***CAEAGLLayer*** instead of ***CATiledLayer***.

I was learning ***OpenGL ES 2.0***, but all those tutorials are all about building 3D models. All I want is to be able to apply texture to appropriate area on View.

From what I was reading and thinking I consider that, when image to redraw will be received, I need to convert it to **texture**, get ***rect*** which should be redrew and generate **verteces** from it, then path ***varteces*** and ***texture*** to ***vertex shader***.

Any ideas or advices are welcome.

(Please don't write something like:*"Why you want to use OpenGL instead of CATiledLayer?"* even if it's not best option I want to figure out how to make it work this way).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since there were no responses to my question i will share what I've got. 
First of all I am using ***OpenGL ES 2.0***.

1) I draw two triangles to cover whole screen like this

[image]

to store Vertices and triangles I use following structs (***Color*** value is not used in my case):

```
typedef struct {
    float Position[3];
    float Color[4];
    float TexCoord[2];
} Vertex;

const Vertex Vertices[] = {
    {{1, -1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0}},
    {{1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1}},
    {{-1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1}},
    {{-1, -1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0}}
};

const GLubyte Indices[] = {
    0, 1, 2,
    2, 3, 0
};
```

2) After that done I wait for whole remote screen to load image and than I set that image of whole screen as **texture** using following code:

```
-(void)setupTextureFromCGImage:(CGImageRef)imageRef{

    NSDictionary * options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSNumber numberWithBool:_snapshot.isImageMirrored],
                              GLKTextureLoaderOriginBottomLeft,
                              nil];

    NSError * error;
    GLKTextureInfo * info = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithCGImage:imageRef options:options error:&error];
    if (info == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error loading file: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        return;
    }
    self.effect.texture2d0.name = info.name;
    self.effect.texture2d0.enabled = true;
    _bigTexture = info.name;
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.effect.texture2d0.name);
}
```

This code uses **GLKit**'s **GLKTextureLoader**, however this can be simply replaced with ***glteximage2d()***.

After that view looks similar to this:

[image]

3) When the update received we need image of update and rect to know which part to update:

```
-(void)loadSubImageTextureImageBuffer:(const char *)buffer inRect:(CGRect)rect
{
CGRect rectGL = rect;
rectGL.origin.y = _snapshot.imageRect.size.height - (rectGL.origin.y +     rectGL.size.height);// convert coordinates from UIView's upper left to OpenGL's lower left

glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                    0,
                    rectGL.origin.x,
                    rectGL.origin.y,
                    rectGL.size.width,
                    rectGL.size.height,
                    GL_BGRA,
                    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                    buffer);
}
```

For drawing I use custom shaders not ***GLKView***, they do nothing but mapping texture to vertices.

OpenGL drawing works faster then ***CATiledLayer***, not extremely but still. There are some few glitches which I will investigate in the future.

Hope this will be useful for somebody. If you need some more details feel free to contact me
haawaplus@gmail.com

**P.S**

For now I paused my **CATiledLayer -> OpenGL ES** investigation since i got some other work to do but I will update my answer when I will return to OpenGL.